# choosing exactly n hearts and excatly m hearts

Tags: combinatorics

Two hands of thirteen cards are dealt (without replacement) from an ordinary pack (52 cards). What is the probability
that one hand contains exactly n Hearts, and the other contains exactly m Hearts ?

My solution
Assume $m\ne n$. Then we can choose:
1) the first n hearts in the first hand in ${13\choose k}$.\
2)the other (13-n) cards in ${39\choose 13-n} .\\`\\$
3) other m hearts in ${13-n\choose m}$ and finally 4) the rest of the cards in ${26+n\choose 13-m}$ cards.
we divide the product of these combinations by ${52\choose 13}*{39\choose 13}$.
first question: is this the correct answer?
second question: if m=n, then should we divide by 2!?

Answer (score 1):

There are typos / mistakes in your formula.
It is best to take just one variable, say $k$ hearts in the first hand,$(13-k)$ in the second, then

$Pr = \dfrac{\binom{13}{k}\binom{39}{13-k}\binom{13-k}{13-k}\binom{26+k}{k}}{\binom{52}{13}\binom{39}{13}}$

In your terminology since $n+m=13$, $n$ can never be equal to $m$, and anyway the two hands will always be distinct, thus division by $2$ not at all needed.

---

**Note**

I interpreted the question as all $13$ hearts being in the two hands dealt. If that is not so, pl. put a comment. I'm not very clear what $k$ represented in your question.

---

**Added** after OP's comments

**1.** Assuming $n$ hearts in first hand, $m$ in second, $Pr = \dfrac{\binom{13}{n}\binom{39}{13-n}\binom{13}{m}\binom{26+n}{13-m}}{\binom{52}{13}\binom{39}{13}}$

**2.** Even if $n=m$, and we are only classifying cards as diamonds and non-diamonds, division by $2$ will not be needed. Both the numerator and denominator count the number of ways to place distinct categories of objects in distinct boxes.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Any number of hearts can be chosen, not necessarly 13.

Comment: I have added an answer based on your comment. Division by $2$ not needed.